Algorithm for finding generating sets of projective modules
Suppose $R$ is a (Dedekind) domain and $M$ is a projective module of constant rank over $R$. We know that $M$ is finitely generated over $R$. I'm wondering is there any algorithms to produce a (minimal) generating set of $M$.
In the case that $R$ is a Dedekind domain, we have the classification theorem for finite projective $R$-modules, $M\cong R^{n-1}\oplus I$, where $I$ is a fractional ideal. Even in this case, barely I have no idea how to find a simple enough generating set.
A possible idea I have in mind is, considering $M\otimes_RK$, where $K$ is the quotient field of $R$, one can find a $K$-basis $B = \{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ for $M\otimes_RK$ easily. Is it possible to produce a generating set from this basis? We know that there exists a nonzero $\lambda\in R$ such that $\lambda M\subset \bigoplus_{i=1}^nRe_i$. But I don't know what to do next.
